# How to implement buffering with timeout in RX

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I need to implement an event processing, that is done delayed when there are no new events arriving for a certain period. (I have to queue up a parsing task when the text buffer changed, but I don't want to start the parsing when the user is still typing.)

I'm new in RX, but as far as I see, I would need a combination of BufferWithTime and the Timeout methods. I imagine this to be working like this: it buffers the events until they are received regularly within a specified time period between the subsequent events. If there is a gap in the event flow (longer than the timespan) it should return propagate the events buffered so far.

Having a look at how Buffer and Timeout is implemented, I could probably implement my BufferWithTimeout method (if everyone have one, please share with me), but I wonder if this can be achieved just by combining the existing methods. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reactive Throttle returning all items added within the TimeSpan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8849810/reactive-throttle-returning-all-items-added-within-the-timespan)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias This was 10+ years ago and I don't work on that project anymore, so I cannot verify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>I think `BufferWithTime` is what you are after.</strike>

There is nothing built in, but something like this should work:

Note: If an error occurs from the source, the buffer is not flushed. This matches the current (or current last time I checked) functionality of `BufferWith*`

```
public static IObservable<TSource[]> BufferWithTimeout<TSource>(
    this IObservable<TSource> source, TimeSpan timeout)
{
    return source.BufferWithTimeout(timeout, Scheduler.TaskPool);
}

public static IObservable<TSource[]> BufferWithTimeout<TSource>(
    this IObservable<TSource> source, TimeSpan timeout, IScheduler scheduler)
{
    return Observable.CreateWithDisposable<TSource[]>(observer =>
    {
        object lockObject = new object();
        List<TSource> buffer = new List<TSource>();

        MutableDisposable timeoutDisposable = new MutableDisposable();

        Action flushBuffer = () =>
        {
            TSource[] values;

            lock(lockObject)
            {
                values = buffer.ToArray();
                buffer.Clear();
            }

            observer.OnNext(values);
        };

        var sourceSubscription = source.Subscribe(
            value =>
            {
                lock(lockObject)
                {
                    buffer.Add(value);
                }

                timeoutDisposable.Disposable = 
                    scheduler.Schedule(flushBuffer, timeout);
            },
            observer.OnError,
            () =>
            {
                flushBuffer();
                observer.OnCompleted();
            });

        return new CompositeDisposable(sourceSubscription, timeoutDisposable);
    });
}
```

Comment: BufferWithTime triggers regularly with a time period, but I want to have triggering after a certain idle time.

Comment: Does that not mean that if there is never a gap, you will never receive output?

Comment: yes, if there is never a gap, I don't want to receive any event. But since the events are generated by the key presses of the users and the timeout is 100ms, there will be a gap sooner or later :)

Comment: Updated post compilation fixes and testing.

Comment: Cool! Thx! I'll have a look in detail.

Comment: I had a look. I had to make two corrections to get it properly run: 
1 - the type parameter have to be written out expilictly "return Observable.CreateWithDisposable<TSource[]>(observer =>"
2 - the timeout parameter was missing from the schedule call: "timeoutDisposable.Disposable = scheduler.Schedule(flushBuffer, timeout);"
With these changes, it runs perfect. Thx!

Comment: It seems rx.net has introduced some breaking changes so this code wont compile anymore.

Answer (score 15):

This is quite an old question, but I do believe the following answer is worth mentioning, since all other solutions have forced the user to subscribe manually, track changes, etc.

I offer the following as an "Rx-y" solution.

```
var buffers = source
    .GroupByUntil(
        // yes. yes. all items belong to the same group.
        x => true,
        g => Observable.Amb<int>(
               // close the group after 5 seconds of inactivity
               g.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)),
               // close the group after 10 items
               g.Skip(9)
             ))
    // Turn those groups into buffers
    .SelectMany(x => x.ToArray());
```

Basically, the source is windowed until some observerable defined in terms of the newest window. A new window (grouped observable) is created, and we use that window to determine when the window should close. In this case, I'm closing the window after 5 seconds of inactivity or a maximum length of 10 (9+1).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Richard Szalay's answer I've just been looking into the new `Window` operator from the latest rx release.  It 'kind of' solves you problem in that you can 'buffer with a time out', i.e. get the output within a window of time that lasts until the timeout is reached, but instead of receiving the results as an IEnumerable you actually get them as an IObservable.

Here's a quick example of what I mean:

```
private void SetupStream()
{
    var inputStream = Observable.FromEvent<MouseButtonEventHandler, MouseButtonEventArgs>(
        h => new MouseButtonEventHandler(h), 
        h => MouseDown += h,
        h => MouseDown -= h);

    var timeout = inputStream.Select(evt => Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), Scheduler.Dispatcher))
        .Switch();

    inputStream.Window(() => timeout)
        .Subscribe(OnWindowOpen);
}


private void OnWindowOpen(IObservable<IEvent<MouseButtonEventArgs>> window)
{
    Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Window open"));

    var buffer = new List<IEvent<MouseButtonEventArgs>>();

    window.Subscribe(click =>
    {

        Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Click"));

        buffer.Add(click);

    }, () => ProcessEvents(buffer));
}

private void ProcessEvents(IEnumerable<IEvent<MouseButtonEventArgs>> clicks)
{
    Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Window closed"));

    //...
}
```

Every time the window opens, you receive all the events as and when they come in, store them in a buffer and process when the window completes (which actually happens when the next window opens).

Not sure if Richard would change his example to use `Window` now it's available but thought it might be worth raising as an alternative.

Comment: Interesting. I've been meaning to have a look at the latest release and now I have an excuse!

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to run an operation when the user stops typing for a certain amount of time, and don't necessarily need the intermediate events, then `Throttle` is the operation you're after. Check [here](http://bryanmitchellanderson.com/2010/08/rx-running-a-function-when-the-user-stops-typing/) for an example of its usage in that scenario.

Comment: In my case I needed the changes as well not only the final result (this is a big text block and I only re-parse the changed parts), but you are right, if the individual changes are not interesting, the Throttle is a good option.

Comment: In my application I want to do some processing when the user has stopped moving the Camera in a 3D view. Throttle was a good option for this.

Comment: link is broken, can the example be added to the post?