# Reactive Throttle returning all items added within the TimeSpan

Tags: c#, system.reactive, rx.net

Given an `IObservable<T>` is there a way to use `Throttle` behaviour (reset a timer when an item is added, but have it return a collection of all the items added within that time?

`Buffer` provides a similar functionality it that it chunks the data up into `IList<T>` on every time span or count. But I need that time to reset each time an item is added.

I've seen a similar question here, [Does reactive extensions support rolling buffers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597773/does-reactive-extensions-support-rolling-buffers), but the answers don't seem ideal and it's a little old so I wondered if the release version of Rx-Main now supports this functionality out the box.

Comment: It sounds like my `BufferWithInactivity` answer in http://stackoverflow.com/a/7604825/259769 is what you're asking for. Can you clarify your question please?

Comment: @Enigmativity It is, it's exactly the functionality I'm after. I referenced that question in my question :) But I don't like that answer, the answerer has explicitly stated it's work in progress.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. If the timer gets reset every time an item is "added" (propagated?) how will there be anything to buffer in the first place?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As I [answered in the other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9791385/284795), yes you can! Using the `Throttle` and `Window` methods of `Observable`:

```
public static IObservable<IList<T>> BufferUntilInactive<T>(this IObservable<T> stream, TimeSpan delay)
{
    var closes = stream.Throttle(delay);
    return stream.Window(() => closes).SelectMany(window => window.ToList());
}
```

Comment: Nice answer! But shouldn't one publish the stream using `return stream.Publish(hot =>...`), to avoid subscribing twice to cold observables?

Answer (score 4):

I amended Colonel Panic's [`BufferUntilInactive`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9791918/11178549) operator by adding a `Publish` component, so that it works correctly with cold observables too:

```
/// <summary>Projects each element of an observable sequence into consecutive
/// non-overlapping buffers, which are produced based on time and activity,
/// using the specified scheduler to run timers.</summary>
public static IObservable<IList<T>> BufferUntilInactive<T>(
    this IObservable<T> source, TimeSpan dueTime, IScheduler scheduler = default)
{
    scheduler ??= Scheduler.Default;
    return source.Publish(published =>
        published
            .Window(() => published.Throttle(dueTime, scheduler))
            .SelectMany(window => window.ToList())
    );
}
```

For completeness I've also added an optional `IScheduler` parameter, which configures the scheduler where the timer is run.

Comment: For a `BufferUntilInactive` variant that also has a `maxCount` parameter, you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597773/does-reactive-extensions-support-rolling-buffers/69791552#69791552).

Comment: **Caution:** there is currently [a bug](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/issues/1846 "Items not processed, when busy processing previous items") in the `Window` operator (Rx version 5.0), that can result in values being lost. The conditions that can trigger the bug are not fully studied at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it work with

[`Observable.BufferWithTimeOrCount<TSource> Method (IObservable<TSource>, TimeSpan, Int32)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff707505.aspx)?

Comment: Nope, the time component will kick in immediately and buffer everything until that time elapsed, and the count will buffer n number of items. I need the buffer time to reset when an item is added (like Throttle).