# "Buffer until quiet" behavior from Reactive?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

My problem is sort of like the one the [Nagle algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) was created to solve, but not exactly. What I'd like is to buffer the `OnNext` notifications from an `IObservable<T>` into a sequence of `IObservable<IList<T>>`s like so:

1. When the first `T` notification arrives, add it to a buffer and start a countdown
2. If another `T` notification arrives before the countdown expires, add it to the buffer *and restart the countdown*
3. Once the countdown expires (i.e. the producer has been silent for some length of time), forward all the buffered `T` notifications as a single aggregate `IList<T>` notification.
4. If the buffer size grows beyond some maximum before the countdown expires, send it anyway.

`IObservable<IList<T>> Buffer(this IObservable<T>, Timespan, int, IScheduler)` looked promising, but it appears to send aggregate notifications out at regular intervals rather than doing the "start the timer when the first notification arrives and restart it when additional ones arrive" behavior I'd like, and it also sends out an empty list at the end of each time window if no notifications have been produced from below.

I do *not* want to drop any of the `T` notifications; just buffer them.

Does anything like this exist, or do I need to write my own?

Comment: You may be able to modify [the answer in this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655437/how-to-implement-buffering-with-timeout-in-rx) to add the "send on buffer full".

Comment: Related: [Reactive Throttle Returning All Items Added Within The TimeSpan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8849810/reactive-throttle-returning-all-items-added-within-the-timespan)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some similar questions exist on SO but not exactly like this.
Here's an extension method that does the trick.

```
public static IObservable<IList<TSource>> BufferWithThrottle<TSource>
                                          (this IObservable<TSource> source,
                                           int maxAmount, TimeSpan threshold)
{
    return Observable.Create<IList<TSource>>((obs) =>
    {
        return source.GroupByUntil(_ => true,
                                   g => g.Throttle(threshold).Select(_ => Unit.Default)
                                         .Merge( g.Buffer(maxAmount).Select(_ => Unit.Default)))
                     .SelectMany(i => i.ToList())
                     .Subscribe(obs);
    });
}
```

Comment: That does appear to work. Can you explain what it's doing at all? I haven't encountered `GroupByUntil` before.

Comment: Sure. `GroupByUntil` groups incoming values until the `Observable` provided as the second parameter provides a value. In this case we group all notifications to same group and wait for a value from either `Throttle` or `Buffer` (hence the `Merge`). The former ensures the silence threshold, the latter ensures the maximum limit.

Comment: Nice solution. I proposed a slight variation instead of using Buffer that will use less memory in cases of large buffers or a busy stream

Answer (score 6):

Interesting operator. Supertopi's answer is a good one, but there's an improvement that can be made. If `maxAmount` is large, and/or the rate of notifications is high, then using `Buffer` will burn the GC by allocating buffers that get thrown away shortly afterwards.

In order to close each `GroupBy` Observable after a `maxAmount` is reached, you don't need to capture a `Buffer` of all of those elements just to know when it's full. Based on Supertopi's answer, you could change it slightly to the following. Instead of collecting a `Buffer` of `maxAmount` elements, it just signals after it has seen `maxAmount` elements on the stream.

```
public static IObservable<IList<TSource>> BufferWithThrottle<TSource>(this IObservable<TSource> source, int maxAmount, TimeSpan threshold)
{
    return Observable.Create<IList<TSource>>((obs) =>
    {
        return source.GroupByUntil(_ => true,
                                   g => g.Throttle(threshold).Select(_ => Unit.Default)
                                         .Merge(g.Take(maxAmount)
                                                 .LastAsync()
                                                 .Select(_ => Unit.Default)))
                     .SelectMany(i => i.ToList())
                     .Subscribe(obs);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Nice solutions. In my opinion, creating behaviour using existing operators is just for convenience but not for performance.

Also, we should always return IEnumerable instead of IList.
Returning the least derived type (IEnumerable) will leave you the most leeway to change the underlying implementation down the track.

Here is my version to implement custom operator.

```
public static IObservable<IEnumerable<TValue>> BufferWithThrottle<TValue>(this IObservable<TValue> @this, int maxAmount, TimeSpan threshold)
    {
        var buffer = new List<TValue>();

        return Observable.Create<IEnumerable<TValue>>(observer =>
        {
            var aTimer = new Timer();
            void Clear()
            {
                aTimer.Stop();
                buffer.Clear();
            }
            void OnNext()
            {
                observer.OnNext(buffer);
                Clear();
            }
            aTimer.Interval = threshold.TotalMilliseconds;
            aTimer.Enabled = true;
            aTimer.Elapsed += (sender, args) => OnNext();
            var subscription = @this.Subscribe(value =>
            {
                buffer.Add(value);
                if (buffer.Count >= maxAmount)
                    OnNext();
                else
                {
                    aTimer.Stop();
                    aTimer.Start();
                }
            });
            return Disposable.Create(() =>
            {
                Clear();
                subscription.Dispose();
            });
        });
    }
```

By testing the performance comparing to other solutions, it can save up to 30% CPU power and resolve the memory issue.

Comment: I think your answer is not complete?

Comment: @MohammadKanan Yes, because I was failed to make it colorful for my first post. So I keep editing my answer. It should be okay now.

Comment: One benefit of composing existing operators instead of rolling your own is that it gives you high confidence in the result. You code *looks* like it will work, but I would want to put it though a lot of testing before using it in a production environment (in the time since I asked the question, my need for this operator has disappeared). Still worth an upvote

Comment: I'd also quibble with changing the type from IList to IEnumerable. Yes, it gives you the flexibility to swap in something different later, but doing so may trigger bugs for the caller if they were (knowingly or unknowingly) relying on you returning a specific type. For example, if you started returning a lazily-evaluated IEnumerable when you'd been handing out List before. Sure, that's their own fault, but in general, I like to make it as difficult as possible to misuse my APIs. Your mileage may vary, but I prefer to be fairly specific about what I'm returning.

Answer (score 0):

In the article about rx, posted Ian Griffiths on [site](https://introtorx.com), there is an example of the implementation of such an operator in the section [LINQ Operators and Composition](https://introtorx.com/chapters/key-types). A detailed description of his work is also given there.

```
static class RxExt
{
    public static IObservable<IList<T>> Quiescent<T>( this IObservable<T> src,
        TimeSpan minimumInactivityPeriod, IScheduler scheduler) {
        IObservable<int> onoffs =
            from _ in src
            from delta in
                Observable.Return(1, scheduler)
                    .Concat(Observable.Return(-1, scheduler)
                        .Delay(minimumInactivityPeriod, scheduler))
            select delta;
        IObservable<int> outstanding = onoffs.Scan(0, (total, delta) => total + delta);
        IObservable<int> zeroCrossings = outstanding.Where(total => total == 0);
        return src.Buffer(zeroCrossings);
    }
}
```