# Observable Throttled Buffer?

Tags: c#, observable, system.reactive, throttling

I am developing a file monitoring system. What I need is to record each change, collect them to buffer, and throttled emit.
In other words, when there is a change, the buffer start recording. And if there's no change in 200ms, then emit all the changes (either one by one or collection is OK). The `Throttle` method does not meet my requirement, since it only return the **last** element in each group (the green and purple point in the following diagram).
[image: Buffer]

I've coded following (using `GroupByUntil`) as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655437/how-to-implement-buffering-with-timeout-in-rx/22873833#22873833) by cwharris:

```
using var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher("some_path")
{
    Filter = "*.*",
    NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.Size,
    IncludeSubdirectories = true,
    EnableRaisingEvents = true,
};

var Files = Observable.FromEventPattern<FileSystemEventHandler, FileSystemEventArgs>(
    h => watcher.Created += h, h => watcher.Created -= h)
    .Select(x => x.EventArgs.FullPath)
    .GroupByUntil(x => true, g => g.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200)))
    .SelectMany(x => x.ToArray());


using IDisposable handle = Files.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\n", x)));
```

Is there any other way to implement this? e.g. Using `Buffer` and `bufferClosingSelector`?

Comment: I think he means debouncing. Since many people confuse debouncing and throttling (including the Rx operator), it’s a pretty fair mistake.

Comment: @Shlomo both debouncing and throttling cause elements to be dropped, and I am not seeing any dropped element in the marble diagram. My guess is that the OP is searching for this: [Reactive Throttle returning all items added within the TimeSpan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8849810/reactive-throttle-returning-all-items-added-within-the-timespan).

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @Theodor Zoulias, since it's a hot observable, the solution becomes:

```
var Files = Observable.FromEventPattern<FileSystemEventHandler, FileSystemEventArgs>(
    h => watcher.Created += h, h => watcher.Created -= h)
    .Select(x => x.EventArgs.FullPath);

var emits = Files.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200));
var FinalFiles = Files.Window(() => emits).SelectMany(x => x.ToArray());
```