# Observable throttling

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I am trying to implement an event throttling with reactive extensions.
I have a system where events might be raised with high frequency for a specific user or other entity type.
What i need is to delay the event for specific amount of time and once the timeout expires raise the event with the last value.

What i have done is this

```
 private Subject<int> userBalanceObservable = new Subject<int>();
 userBalanceObservable.Sample(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(sampleSeconds))
            .Subscribe(sample => OnRaiseBalanceEvent(sample));
```

when event occurs

```
userBalanceObservable.OnNext(userId);
```

**Edit**

The problem with this approach is that the event is raised for the last value passed to OnNext, what i would actually need is to have a dellay for each value passed to OnNext.

E.g OnNext(1),OnNext(2),OnNext(3) i would need to have a delayed call for 1,2,3 instead i am getting only the last value which is 3.

Comment: Next time try to post a Minimum Complete Verifiable Example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we know exactly what you are trying to achieve. Ideally with unit tests.

Comment: You really need to show us all of the code - especially what's happening in `OnRaiseBalanceEvent` and how `userBalanceObservable` gets its values. Just as a small hint though, if you're using a `Subject` you're probably doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Sample publishes the last value every time the sample interval is hit. If that is the behaviour you require then it is fine. Have a look at http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/13_TimeShiftedSequences.html#Sample For more information + other ways to slow down the emission rate.

**In regards to the new information about your question:**

If you want to emit all the values after a certain timeout has been hit you can group these until your timeout has hit (NOTE: You can run out of memory if you keep adding events without your timeout ever hitting due to the frequencey of event emissions)

You can create a Buffer which fills up until a `Debounce` timeout hits, see this answer on SO for pointers: [How to implement buffering with timeout in RX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655437/how-to-implement-buffering-with-timeout-in-rx)

Comment: Actually it seem that it doesn't really work as i would expect.
What i need is to have a sample delayed for each specific item and not generally any item. E.g OnNext(1),OnNext(2),OnNext(3) i would expect to have a delayed call for 1,2,3 instead i am getting only the last value which is 3. Does reactive extensions support such functionality ?

Comment: Try Delay. See http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/13_TimeShiftedSequences.html#Delay

Comment: @NullReference - That's not what you asked for in the question. Can you please update the question?

Answer (score 1):

Does not just [buffering](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229813(v=vs.103).aspx) work? The only "issue" is that OnRaiseBalanceEvent has to work with list instead just one value but all problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection ;)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Reactive.Subjects;
using System.Reactive.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

      Subject<int> userBalanceObservable = new Subject<int>();
    userBalanceObservable.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)) //get List of items
                     .Subscribe(sampleList => ProcessSamples(sampleList));

      int cont = 0;

      while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
        {
        userBalanceObservable.OnNext(cont);
        cont++;
        userBalanceObservable.OnNext(cont);
        cont++;
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
      }

    }

    private static void ProcessSamples(IList<int> sampleList)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("[{0}]", string.Join(", ", sampleList.ToArray()));
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm i think buffer can do the job. I can use .Where(x=>x.Count >0) to silence empty sequences and Distinct() to get just one instance of value.